# What harm do disabled media tags do to a website?

Tags: gtmetrix

I'm having trouble understanding why I can't just leave disabled media tags on GTM and I can't find the answer anywhere. Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: How did you find out they were harmful?

Comment: I'm asking because there's zero coverage of this topic on Google (either that, or it's being masked by accessibility pages).

Comment: It's considered to be a malpractice in some ad companies I've worked in the past.